# Java Prepared Statement not working with retrieving data

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Is there a difference when use a prepared statement in a public and private functions?

I have a two functions `insertRecord()` and `GetAllRecords()`, the problem is `employeeCode` doesn't have a value when I call it on `GetAllRecords`, but it works with `insertRecord()` as I can store and read them on the database. I can't retrieve them for display because it seems like `employeeCode` doesn't have a value in `GetAllRecords`

```
private void insertRecord(Connection conn){
    try {
        PreparedStatement pstmnt= conn.prepareStatement("insert into "+sqlInsert()+"(EmployeeName, EmployeeCode, EmployeeSales, EmployeeGross, EmployeeCommission, EmployeeResult)"+ "values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        pstmnt.setString(1, employeeName);
        pstmnt.setString(2, employeeCode);
        pstmnt.setDouble(3, employeeSales);
        pstmnt.setDouble(4, gross);
        pstmnt.setDouble(5, commission);
        pstmnt.setDouble(6, result);

        //now commit to database
        pstmnt.executeUpdate();
    } catch(SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this is my GetAllRecords function

```
public ResultSet getAllRecords(Connection conn) {
    ResultSet records = null;
    try{
        String sql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM SalesCodeA UNION ALL SELECT * FROM SalesCodeB UNION ALL SELECT * FROM SalesCodeC ) t WHERE t.EmployeeCode=?";
        PreparedStatement pstmnt= conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmnt.setString(1, employeeCode);

        records= pstmnt.executeQuery();
    } catch(SQLException sqle){
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
    return records;
}
```

It's gonna work properly if I change the value of `pstmnt.setString(1, employeeCode);` to let's say `pstmnt.setString(1, "A");` it's going to output the table that has the column `EmployeeCode = "A"`.

This is how I declared employeeCode inside my Bean:

```
private String employeeCode;

public String getEmployeeCode() {
    return employeeCode;
}

public void setEmployeeCode(String employeeCode) {
    this.employeeCode=employeeCode;
}
```

and on the Helper class:

```
public class EmployeeHelper {

    public static EmployeeBean getInstance(String employeeCode) {
        employee.setEmployeeCode(employeeCode);
        return employee;
    }

}
```

Comment: So if you write `setString(1, "A")` it works, but `setString(1, employeeCode)` doesn't? Have you considered that `employeeCode` may then not have the value `"A"` at the time you execute that code? Have you then considered that if you want us to help, in any way, it would be prudent to show us how `employeeCode` is declared? How it is assigned a value? You know, *any* meaningful information about that variable?

Comment: Hint: please take the time to properly format all of your source code.

Comment: I already edited the code, how come it is working on InsertRecord() ? the employeeCode works fine as I can insert records on the database.

Comment: @Renzz Can you share code of your Domain also

Comment: @Renzz what are you using to retrieve value??
getter & setter?